# Mail folder in reverse alphabetical order

Tags: macos, mail.app, catalina

After upgrading 10.15 Catalina, the folders in Mail are sorted in reverse alphabetical order. I am connecting to Gmail.

Anyone has similar issue?

Comment: Isn't there some sort settings in view menu as in older version ? you can search it using help menu

Comment: Not for the folders. I have been using mail for years this is the first time I see this issue.

Comment: Oh I misread it. can they be dragged and repositioned ? ofc, it's a question worth asking if there are too many